# CSS not working in Non-firefox browsers in <option> tag

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

my css code is

```
.sele {
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform:scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0.75; 
    margin: 0 10px 5px 0; 
}
.sele:hover {
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
    -o-transform:scale(1.1);
    box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 30px gray; 
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

I am using it in `<option>` tag but it is working only with Mozilla Firefox and not with others.
you can browse this live at http://jsfiddle.net/baibav/D5Fdq/5/

Comment: you really use a class with the name `sele`? or better the class name is `sele` ?

Comment: Try assigning the same values to transform attribute in both the classes.

Comment: You have a typo in your fiddle <select class="sel" ->  <select class="sele"  see this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/D5Fdq/2/

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
.sele {
    transform:scale(0.8);
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform:scale(0.8);
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    opacity: 0.75; 
    margin: 0 10px 5px 0; 
}
.sele:hover {
    transform:scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
    -o-transform:scale(1.1);
    box-shadow:0 0 30px gray; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 30px gray; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 30px gray; 
    opacity: 1; 
}
```

Comment: @user2541787 it works in chrome and opera and safari.. (up to date browsers..)

Comment: I realized my my mistake in asking question actually this is for <option> not for <select> Sorry for inconvenience can you help me now in this ?

Comment: @user2541787 I think that transform don't supports options.. The best alternative is, that you make a list.